# Laravel-5.5: Where I can use my if's for display date in needed format?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have messages in my database. And in messages have sended dates. I have **Message** model.

#### Code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Message extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'subject', 'message', 'from', 'to', 'created_at'];

    public function sender() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'from');
    }

    public function receiver() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'to');
    }

    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('M d H:i');
    }
}
```

How I can display today sended messages in date format `H:i`. And how I can display all messages which sended in this year (without today sended messages) in date format `M-d`. And how display sended messages in past years in date format `Y-m-d`. Where I must write code for check date of message and return needed format?

Here my code for get date diff:

```
echo $today =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $message_date = "2018-01-07 01:34:35"; // Work date('H:i')
  // $message_date = "2017-01-07 01:34:35"; // Work date('Y-m-d')
  // $message_date = "2017-12-07 01:34:35"; // Work date('M d')

$date_diff = date_diff(date_create($today), date_create($message_date));

if($date_diff->days == 0) echo '<p>'.date('H:i').'</p>';
if($date_diff->y == 0 AND $date_diff->m > 0) echo '<p>'.date('M d').'</p>';
if($date_diff->y > 0) echo '<p>'.date('Y-m-d').'</p>';
```

I wrote simple code in Laravel but it not work end return `"Not working!"`

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    $today =  date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $message_date = date_create($date); 
    $date_diff = date_diff($today, $message_date);

    if($date_diff->days == 0) return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('H:i');
    if($date_diff->y == 0 AND $date_diff->m > 0) return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('M d');
    if($date_diff->y > 0) return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d');

    return "Not working!";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't set accessor for the `created_at` date to transform it to a string. Remove the accessor or rename it.

> How I can display today sended messages in date format `H:i`.

Get messages:

```
Message::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();
```

> And how I can display all messages which sended in this year (without today sended messages) in date format M-d

```
Message::whereBetween('created_at', [now()->startOfYear(), Carbon::yesterday()->endOfDay()])->get();
```

> And how display sended messages in past years in date format Y-m-d.

```
Message::where('created_at', '<', now()->startOfYear())->get();
```

To display messages in the Blade template, use `format()`, for example:

```
@foreach ($messages as $message)
    {{ $message->created_at->format('H:i') }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: Your whereBetween() query not work! Error give `Non-static method Carbon\Carbon::startOfYear() should not be called statically
`

Comment: I add `use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;` but not work @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: Work all fine! Thanks @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: Can I specify the date format for the message in the controller itself? Simply then I will unite the entire message into one array and return it to the view. @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: @MaxNet you can create three accessors like `getCraetedYmdAttribute` to convert `created_at` to a string with specified format and use these accessors with `{{ $message->created_ymd }}`

Comment: Ok @Alexey Mezenin. Generaly +5 for answer ))

Comment: @MaxNet that's why I've told you to remove accessor for `created_at` in my answer. If you want to use `format()` you should remove the accessor. Or you could create three accessors and use new dynamic properties instead of `format()`

Comment: Yes, yes! I already delete it now and remove my sended comment. @Alexey